# How to find average gap between dates?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table of items, every one has it's start time and end time.

For example:

```
| id      | item | start      | end        |
+---------+------+------------+------------+
|    2703 | 223  | 2003-12-30 | 2004-01-16 |
|   47029 | 223  | 2004-04-21 | 2005-01-06 |
| 1386593 | 223  | 2005-04-19 | 2005-04-19 |
| 1386739 | 223  | 2005-04-19 | 2006-12-07 |
| 1432862 | 223  | 2006-02-08 | 2006-02-10 |
```

I'd like to find gaps between items (days between one's end with next start). Gap between first two items in example is 93 days, between last 2 there is overlap 302 days, which is counted as zero. So gaps for example table are:

```
96
103
0
0
```

My goal is to find average gap (49.75 in this example) or other-words sum of gap days (199).

Optional goals to have: min gap (0) and max gap (103).

My solution for now is iterate over rows and calculate it outside database, but i am looking for prompt solution (inside MySQL). I looked over the aggregate functions but don't have no idea is this possible or not. How is the best way to find such average gap?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select avg(if (diff < 0, 0, diff))
from (
    select datediff(min(t2.start), t1.end) as diff
    from Table1 t1
    inner join Table1 t2 on t1.id < t2.id
    group by t1.end
) a
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea718/23)

Comment: Looks great! I'll try to understand it a bit more deeply now :)

Answer (score 1):

SELECT DATEDIFF(start,end) AS average_gap FROM table

@see `DATEDIFF()` from MySQL docs.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Returns number of days. The method is subtraction, so you need to handle negatives outside the SQL. Otherwise, you can do `AVG(DATEDIFF(start, end))`

Edit:

You can do

```
AVG(GREATEST(DATEDIFF(start,end), 0))
```

Comment: I need datediff between 2 different sequent rows: 2. `start` and 1. `end`.

Answer (score 0):

What about a combination of [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff/) and [AVG](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)

This way you would do SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(start,end)) AS gap

EDIT: dang, beat to the punch! :P

Answer (score 0):

This is not something that you're going to be able to accomplish purely in a SQL query, you're going to have to take the data into your application and determine the gaps and overlaps in these intervals there.

It will not be a trivial bit of code, but it should be interesting to write. I would suggest looping through the list and adding together all of the intersecting intervals until you are left with one or more non-intersecting intervals with which you can calculate the gaps.

Comment: Given that someone answered the question with standard SQL, you might consider deleting this answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
select avg(diff) FROM 
( select @rt:=NULL, 
         @rt := if(datediff(start, @end)<0,0,datediff(start, @end)) diff, 
         @end := end from t) t;
```

Answer (score 0):

This (under some circumstances) can be solved usin just SQL. I would use this VIEW to find all of the intervals:

```
CREATE VIEW items_intervals AS
SELECT
  items.end,
  min(items_1.start) as start
FROM
  items inner join items items_1 on items_1.id > items.id
GROUP BY
  items.end
```

Now all you have to do is to aggregate the data:

```
SELECT
  min(greatest(0,datediff(start,end))),
  max(greatest(0,datediff(start,end))),
  sum(greatest(0,datediff(start,end))),
  avg(greatest(0,datediff(start,end)))
FROM
  items_intervals
```

Of course you can combine both query in just one, but i prefer to keep them separated, they're easier to read.

These query work only if records are ordered correctly using id, otherwise they won't!